# plotly: Is there a way to disable the right axis on adding a secondary axis?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

When setting a figure's specs to have `'secondary_y'=True`, it automatically adds a placeholder for an axis on the right of the figure. Is there any way to make it go away or change the to span of the subplot?

In the following example see the differences in the right margin of the plot.

[image]

For an easy reproduction:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

make_subplots(specs=[[{'secondary_y': True}]]).add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[4, 5, 6],
    name="yaxis1 data"
))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create `fig1` and `fig2` and look at their layout.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig1 = make_subplots(specs=[[{'secondary_y': True}]]).add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[4, 5, 6],
    name="yaxis1 data"
))

fig2 = make_subplots().add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[4, 5, 6],
    name="yaxis1 data"
))
```

When we look at the layout for each fig, the x-axis domain is different between the two:

```
>>> fig1.layout['xaxis']['domain']
(0.0, 0.94)
>>> fig2.layout['xaxis']['domain']
(0.0, 1.0)
```

So we can set `fig1` to have the same xaxis domain as `fig2`:

```
fig1.layout['xaxis']['domain'] = (0,1)
```

Comment: Great answer. I did that but couldn't find the right property. Many thanks.

Comment: No problem - glad to have helped!